# First time fatal error lost

Tags: php, twilio

Hello?  Is anybody in there?

I've used this before years ago now I'm back.  First time gives me this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Services_Twilio_TinyHttpException in /home/www/skyphilly6.com/twill/twilio-php/Services/Twilio/TinyHttp.php:119 Stack trace: #0 /home/www/skyphilly6.com/twill/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php(178): Services_Twilio_TinyHttp->__call('post', Array) #1 /home/www/skyphilly6.com/twill/twilio-php/Services/Twilio/ListResource.php(92): Base_Services_Twilio->createData('/2010-04-01/Acc...', Array) #2 /home/www/skyphilly6.com/twill/twilio-php/Services/Twilio/Rest/Calls.php(32): Services_Twilio_ListResource->_create(Array) #3 /home/www/skyphilly6.com/twill/index.php(9): Services_Twilio_Rest_Calls->create('8052629166', '8058130331', 'htttttp://demo.twi...') #4 {main} thrown in /home/www/skyphilly6.com/twill/twilio-php/Services/Twilio/TinyHttp.php on line 119

Here's my short code tried many additional lines same result:

```
<?php
require('./twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); 
$version = "2010-04-01";
$account_sid = 'ACcfc1ba0d12c58180319486144bef540e'; $auth_token =  'washere'; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token, $version); 
$client->account->calls- >create('8052629166','8058133333','htttttp://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/');
?>
```

Also tried uncommenting this same result:

```
<?php
require('./twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); 
$version = "2010-04-01";
//$account_sid = 'SK5b9d2d022b971335e17ee50c813ae231'; $auth_token =  'was'; 
$account_sid = 'ACcfc1ba0d12c58180319486144bef540e'; $auth_token =  'was'; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token, $version); 
//try {
//$call=
$client->account->calls->create('8052629166','8058133333','htttttp://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/');
//,array( 
//'Method' => 'GET',  
//'FallbackMethod' => 'GET',  
//'StatusCallbackMethod' => 'GET',    
//'Record' => 'false', ));
//echo 'Started call: ' . $call->sid;
//} catch (Exception $e) { echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage(); }
?>
```

Please point me in the right direction.

Added:

```
$http = new Services_Twilio_TinyHttp('https://api.twilio.com',
array('curlopts' => array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
))
);
//$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, "2010-04-01", $http);
$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token, $version,$http);
```

Noticed it doesn't matter what I use for my token same error
Can't find the error log:

```
$client->http->debug = true;
```

Hello?

Comment: What version of the PHP helper library are you using?

Comment: It says USER_AGENT = 'twilio-php/4.10.0'; just downloaded.

Comment: I've noticed you're using a nonexistent URL too. Have you tried with just "htttttp://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/"?

Comment: It works in the API Explorer with few changes.  My phone rings!  Something wrong with my PHP configuration on Freehostia.com?  Should I run PHP locally?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, had to add a few "t"'s to post here, links not allowed.

Comment: Sounds complicated http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php it has to run on another server eventually.

Comment: This might be the SSL Validation exception that can happen. Can you check this FAQ page and see if it helps: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/docs/faq.rst#ssl-validation-exceptions

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "with just"?

Comment: Sorry, ignore that comment. Could you check the FAQ I just linked to?

Comment: Added:

    $http = new Services_Twilio_TinyHttp(
    'https://api.twilio.com',
    array('curlopts' => array(
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    ))
    );
    //$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, "2010-04-01", $http);
    $client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token, $version,$http);

Noticed it doesn't matter what I use for my token same error

Comment: I'm the only one to see this error?  Nobody has any ideas?  It's been 10 days and many views...

Comment: Taking a look again at this. :)

Comment: What version of libcurl is installed on the server? Could you try updating it? https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/docs/faq.rst#upgrade-your-version-of-libcurl

Comment: It appears curl extensions are disabled completely on Freehostia.  How else can I run this demo?

Comment: You could try using the Heroku free tier? It works with PHP and has curl extensions enabled. Check out this article for getting started: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#introduction